# How to make one css for each html?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, gruntjs

I am using grunt-uncss to concatenate all the used css rules and make one css file for each html. This is my current `Gruntfile.js`:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {

/*
  var src1=new Array("./4dlife/tools/experiments/index.html","./4dlife/tools/experiments/tests/test_resources_provider.html");

  var dest1=new Array("1.css","2.css");
*/
  var i=0;
  var obj = [{'1.css':'./4dlife/tools/experiments/index.html'}, {'2.css':'./4dlife/tools/experiments/tests/test_resources_provider.html'}];


  grunt.initConfig({

   // Remove unused CSS across multiple files, compressing the final output
    uncss: {
    dist: {
      files: obj
    },
      options: {
        compress:true
      }
    }

  });

  // Load the plugins
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-uncss');
  // Default tasks.
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['uncss']);


}
```

The output of this is :

> Running "uncss:dist" (uncss) task
>
> ReferenceError: Can't find variable:require
>
> > file:///home/pc009/code/4dlife_repo/4dlife/tools/experiments/tests/test_resources_provider.html:35
>
> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
>
> > file:///home/pc009/code/4dlife_repo/4dlife/tools/experiments/index.html:35
> >     File 1.css created: 101.86 kB → 14.62 kB
>
> Done, without errors.

Basically it is only working for the first file(`obj[0]`) in the array and none of the other files.

However, if I put `obj[0]` or `obj[1]` hard-coded then it works fine for both.But I need to do it in one go because I need to perform this task on over 350 files. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay since the automated task was not working in grunt for uncss, I decided to write a script which would take one src and one dest, and replace the line in the grunt file every time and run it.